# Search about a photo description in a database python

Tags: python, flask

Flask Blueprint
I have to use that route in order to search about a specific photo description.
If we have two photos with the same description, they both should appear.
The photos are in a database.

```
@search_bp.route('/search/<query_string>', methods=['GET'])
def search(query_string):
    rq=RiskQuery('./folder/MyDB.db')
    rq.instructions("SELECT * FROM pics WHERE description = %s ORDER By time desc"%(query_string))
    rq.do()
    record = '<h1>Photos</h1>'
    for r in rq.format_results().split('\n\n\n'):
        record+='%s'%(paragraph(r))
    return record+'</table>\n'
```

The function paragraph( ):

```
def paragraph(n):
    if n.strip()=='':
        return ''
    list=n.split(',')
    picture_path=list[2].strip()
    picture_name=list[3].strip()
    img = Image.open(picture_path)
    img.thumbnail((400, 300))
    img.save('./folder/pics/'+picture_name, 'jpg')
    result='<p>'
    result+='<i>%s</i><br/>'%(list[0])
    result+='<i>%s</i><br/>'%(list[1])
    result+='<a href="%s"><img src="./folder/pics/%s""></a>'%(picture_path,picture_name)
    return result+'</p>'
```

When I have tried to test the code by typing:
`localhost/search/look`
I've got:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: look`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line of code

```py
rq.instructions("SELECT * FROM pics WHERE description = %s ORDER By time desc"%(query_string))
```

to

```py
rq.instructions(f"SELECT * FROM pics WHERE description = '{query_string}' ORDER By time desc")
```

I guess the problem is the SQL query is not correct because of the string comparison.

in SQL, we need to have a quote in the `WHERE` clause to find a match of the value.

I noticed that your query uses `description` column as a column, are you sure you want to find the exact match keyword or any keyword from that `description` value?

you might try to use `LIKE`

```py
rq.instructions(f"SELECT * FROM pics WHERE description LIKE '%{query_string}%' ORDER By time desc")
```

reference: [LIKE operator](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_like.asp)

Comment: Thank you, there is no error left but I don't know why I did not get the pictures with that description (query-string).

Comment: Have you tried to run that SQL from your SQL editor and get the expected data? because using `=` means your query needs to find an exact match keyword, but if you need some part of the description, you need to use `LIKE` instead of `=`, I will update my answer to give you more hints.

Comment: I've used `LIKE` but even that the picture does not appear.

Comment: I think you need to double-check again with the SQL editor to ensure that your SQL query works and it can provide you with the correct data.

Comment: I have used the same structure in order to get the database information and it worked but here it did not.